# Difference between Unity's Camera.ScreenPointToRay and Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint?

Tags: unity, unityscript

What is the difference between Unity's  `Camera.ScreenPointToRay` and `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`. And where we can use these. I've watched some tutorial and documentation but I didn't get a clear understanding.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear: **ScreenPointToRay**: `Returns a ray going from camera through a screen point.` **ScreenToWorldPoint**: `Transforms 'position' from screen space into world space.`

Comment: @Hellium Thank you so much for your response now I've got the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScreenPointToRay returns a ray, basically something pointing in the direction of the mouse from the location of the camera.

ScreenToWorldPoint point actually returns a 3d position under the mouse.